# XML vs JSON to represent database data

Tags: xml, json, database

I am trying to understand which of these two technologies, XML or JSON, is better to use for data from a DB. I need to parse data from one of these files and use it my program. And I am trying to see which APIs should I consider for ease of use and design perspective.

Answer (score 4):

**Choose XML if**

- There's already an industry standard XSD to follow.
- Validation afforded by creating a new XSD is important to you or your
  callers.
- You need to transform the data to another XML form.  (XSLT works wonders for transformations.)
- Or, you have to represent mixed content (tags mixed within text).

**Choose JSON if**

- The closer fit to JavaScript is valuable to you or your callers.
- You prefer a lighter-weight solution.
- Or, the reasons mentioned above for choosing XML do not apply to you.